# Is there a way to see who changed a page from published to private in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I've got a page on my wordpress site that keeps getting set as private.

I've got a feeling it's one of the admins on the site, I've checked revisions but it looks like the publish status is not recorded as part of that functionality.

Is there a way to see who changed this setting and when?

Any Guidance would be appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: There is a plugin which might help you out: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/. As listed in their functionalities you can track if the status of any Post, Page and Custom Post Type changes. (And also who changed it)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks - will give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin stream could also help:

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/stream/

Or you could use the post status transition hook:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

and the ID of the post in question to fire up a admin notice or a automated mail to the person who changes the status.
"I know who you are, please stop this" - haha